# Does the "-server" option to the JVM need to be the very first option?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Does the "-server" option to the JVM need to be the very first option?   I read somewhere that this was the case and I can no longer find the documentation any longer.  On the other hand , every single "example" given by Oracle suggests that this is the case.  Does anyone know the answer and know what the link is to prove it?

Comment: why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I have, and I believe I am right, but don't know for sure.

Answer (score 6):

If I write a class with only this in its main method:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));
```

And run it without `-server`, I get this:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
```

But if I run it with the `-server` flag, at anywhere, including the first option or last option, I get this:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM
```

So it appears to not make any difference. Tested this with Oracle's Java 6 and 7.

On linux, using JDK 1.5.0_22, it seems it's defaulted as the server VM. Whether I use `-server` or not, it comes up as the Server VM unless I use `-client`, which I can use anywhere on the command line's list of options.

Comment: Ok, perhaps it was a JSDK5.0 wierdness?  Thanks for the answer.